# Sort the arrays foreach row in pyspark dataframe

Tags: arrays, sorting, pyspark

i need to sort the lignes of pyspark data frame , the only solutions that i found is how to sort a whole column .
To be more clear , i want this

: [image: my dataframe]

to give me : [3 , 19]
with no changes in the order of column
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this solution and it worked with me :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_sort
dataframe = dataframe.withColumn('column name', F.array_sort('column name'))
```